# Why can't our universe be spherical?

Tags: general-relativity, universe, space

if we happen to follow the bigbang singularity hypothesis, when he explosion occured shouldn't it expand in all directions. Seemingly our universe shouldn't have any boundaries. I searched for the question and found the post: it talks about balloon analogy. can anyone explain that in leyman language. Thanks. Just to sum it up Q1 Why cant our universe be spherical? Q2 What is balloon analogy?

Comment: Hi Aaditya. The question I've linked explains what the Big Bang was and how it worked. The universe can't have a shape because there is nothing outside it for it to have a shape in i.e. the universe isn't an object with some shape that is embedded in something bigger. The balloon analogy is very misleading in this respect.

Comment: @JohnRennie thanks i will check it out and see if it adressess my issues.

Comment: @JohnRennie the question definitely solved my first question, i searched under shape of universe so i never saw that question. Though still i would love to know about balloon analogy, should i reword my question or post a new one

Comment: @AadityaCool actually, for that you should [search a bit yourself](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5778). If you have more specific questions after searching, it's probably best to post them separately.

Comment: @DavidZ thanks, I will search and post only then afterwards.

Comment: In an infinite universe or multiverse, like the one whose description has been attempted in the various answers to the preferred question "Did the Big Bang happen at a point?", the question of whether it's spherical cannot, of course, be definitively established, but its probability (or lack thereof) can be extrapolated from data in the region observable by whatever beings might be wanting to establish that probability.  At the moment, the data may be favoring sphericity, as described in the recent paper "Planck evidence for a closed Universe and a possible crisis for cosmology".

Comment: For my previous comment to make sense, I should point out that, in the "for determined readers only" section of John Rennie's answer to the preferred question, he makes clear that "infinite" was only an approximate version for "lacking an edge", which would interfere with the usual assumption that the universe is (on extremely large scales) homogeneous, because any points on the edge would differ from those inboard from that edge: They would actually be "half-points", or something like that. In effect, that answer was that it could consist of an infinite no. of spheres within larger spheres.

Comment: A spherical universe would, in fact, add an uncertain form of possibly infinite variety to cosmology, because of the apparently unending variations in pi.  This would not be a possibility in a universe consisting entirely of planes and points.

Comment: In fact, the possibly endless variations in the division of the circumference by the diameter might bring cosmology down into  a depth to which it has not yet descended, that of biology...!